# How to generate Configuration object from Xml string in C#

Tags: c#, configuration

In our current code, we indicate the path of configure file, and use "ExeConfigurationFileMap" to generate Configuration object:

```
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = GetAppSettingWithPathByName(key); //File path
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Now, we change the strategy.I have read the content of configure file into a string object,how can I use the string object to generate Configuration object?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to convert xml to object

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Just use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var yourtext = doc.ToString();
```

or more simple

```
File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.I have read the content of xml file into a string object ..and I must use this xml string